# How do I make a CRON job to use the export feature of phpmyadmin to export DB

Tags: database, excel, cron

I want to export some tables in my DB to an Excel/Spreadsheet every month.
In PHPMyAdmin there is a direct option of exporting the result of a query to the desired filetype. How do I make use of this export feature without another script to run a cronjob on a monthly basis?

Basically on a CPanel (the DB is hosted in the web) we just have to give the path to the script to be executed via a cronjob. But in PHPMyAdmin there is no such opportunity. Its an included feature of PHPMyAdmin where we generally click and do it mannually. So how do i do it in Cpanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have ssh access to the box? Personally I'd implement this outside of phpmyadmin, as phpmyadmin is just intended for manual operations via the interface. Why not write a simple script to export the db?

Something like `mysqldump database table`.

Answer (score 2):

Being a web-app, the export function is a POST request. In the demo application the URL is `http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/export.php`, and then the post data contains all the required parameters, for example: (You can use Fiddler/Chrome dev tools too view it)

```
token:3162d3b849cf652c2577a45f90022df7
export_type:server
export_method:quick
quick_or_custom:custom
output_format:sendit
filename_template:@SERVER@
remember_template:on
charset_of_file:utf-8
compression:none
what:excel
codegen_structure_or_data:data
codegen_format:0
csv_separator:,
csv_enclosed:"
.....
```

The one tricky bit is the authentication token, but I believe this is also possible to overcome using some configuration and/or extract parameters (like the 'direct login' in http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/)

See here 
[How to send data using curl from Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865146/how-to-send-data-using-curl-from-linux-command-line)

If you want to avoid all this, there are many other web-automation tools that can record the scenario and play it back.

Answer (score 2):

just write a simple php script to connect to your database and use the answer here:
[How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)

Comment: ok you may have some permission issues on this... works fine on my home wamp server but my work's cpanel site gave me denied me access when I tried to use outfile.